Using Facebook ShareDialog to share video on iOS
I'm trying to share a video on iOS via the Facebook SDK (version 17.0.0) ShareDialog. Here's what I tried so far:
let video = ShareVideo(videoAsset: videoAsset)
content.video = video
self.shareDialog = ShareDialog(viewController: self,
                               content: content,
                               delegate: self.delegate)
do {
    try shareDialog?.validate()
} catch {
    print("error")
}
self.shareDialog?.show()

The videoAsset is the PHAsset I get from the camera roll. I tried sharing that on Instagram and it works fine so the asset is not the problem.
The behaviour I'm getting when trying to share on Facebook is that instead of getting a share sheet that asks me where would I like to share the video to (story, feed, groups), I get a Facebook share sheet with nothing in it. I can write a message there and share it, but there is no video attached. Sharing links and images works fine exactly as advertised in the Facebook documentation.
Did anyone else encounter this problem?

It turns out that all I had to do was uninstall the Facebook app and then install it again.
